# Nginx controller Event with message "Scheduled for sync"

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have deployed AWS elb and nginx-controller. I'm using nginx to route a traffic to a different namespace. When I apply ingress resource and describe it, I get:

```
----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

I am unable to reach the host, but its working well with other hosts.

`kubectl describe ing XXXXX`

```
Name:             promethues-ingress-dev
Namespace:        monitoring
Address:          172.20.223.123
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                     Path  Backends
  ----                     ----  --------
  dashboard.dev.xxxx.ai
                           /*   kube-prom-stack-dev-grafana:80 (10.0.1.189:3000)
Annotations:               kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    42m (x4 over 72m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Comment: Am facing same issue !!   any luck in fixing it ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after upgrading Nginx to v1, I ran into an issue with Nginx-controller failing to establish a leader, due to a change in name of the leader election configmap.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7632.

Make sure if you update your Nginx, you also update associated role permissions.